# SQL query for removing characters for a whole column

Tags: sql, r

I have a large dataset. I used SQL Sever design environment to enter some data but now I have a problem because it added some characters like you see in code for brand **basket 2**.

These characters don't seem to be spaces because script under would probably had different result. When I read data into R (my yesterday question) for those brands I inserted manually in design window it has added string r\n\ which might be helpful.

So basically I hope to get the help to get a script with which I can update whole column so when applicable it will cut these 2 characters

```
select Brand, len(Brand) as length1,len(rtrim(Brand))as lenght2 from my table
where brand like 'bask%'
group by Brand

the result is
Brand     length1   length2
basket 1    8       8
basket 2   10       10
```

Comment: I found that last character in the column is 10 in ASCII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRLF is 1310 in Ascii

You could try something like this to replace the CRLF:

```
   REPLACE(REPLACE(Brand, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```